# Windows 10 will not run on Pentium 4 (HP Compaq dc7600)

Tags: windows-10

I have this HP Compaq dc7600 MicroTower and when I try to install windows 10, it freezes at the point where it is launching the windows logo. It has 2.6GHz Pentium 4 processor, 3.5GB RAM and I have 500GB of hard disk space. What could be the problem with it?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your P4 date it may not implement the NX (No-eXecute) bit that is hardcoded into Windows, so if your processor doesn't support this then Windows 10 will never work. I believe the NX bit was hardcoded into Windows 8 and later...

General information for NX bit
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit

Intel introduction of NX bit capable processor came as of Prescott: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_4#Prescott

Comment: I just ran into this problem a few days ago. Grr Microsoft...

Comment: Not really Microsoft's fault if they're thinking about customer security... more why would someone be running such old hardware... admittedly the hardware is tangible and still works so why not? I agree but times are changing and threats are getting worse

Comment: I bought a Windows 10 tablet partially so that I'd still have some version of Windows to work with once 7 became too old for my P4. I liked the tablet so much that I got rid of 7 on the P4 and extended Ubuntu to fill the space.

Comment: It's partially Microsoft's fault because it just hangs with no error messages.  If it only tells you that you're hardware is incompatible, it'll be better.

Answer (score 0):

**None of the socket 478 CPUs supported PAE and NX.**

But DC7600s did come with socket 775.

Intel implemented the XD bit after AMD starting with the **Prescott core**.

So your CPU is only compatible with Windows 10 if it is at least Prescott core on socket LGA775.

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments. I actually downloaded a 32-bit version of windows 10 and it installed successfully. I was previously trying to install a 64 bit version and that is why it was declining, even though the machine processor's architecture is 64-bit. I am now running windows 10 32 bit on that machine.

Comment: Glad it worked.